# Why does my HQL query work, but a Criteria version doesn't?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

My (Fluent) NHibernate schema is a little complicated. The two classes in question here are both country-specific, and inherit from an abstract class. The point behind this is that different country data is stored in different tables. It all works fine, except in the following. This HQL executes fine:

```
dbSession.CreateQuery(@"from DateBlock_US db where
            db.HaveListing.City.LocationID = " + searchLocation.LocationID.ToString()).List<DateBlock>();
```

(I know I should be using SetParameter, but this is just a demo). However, this Criteria doesn't work:

```
dbSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(DateBlock_US))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("HaveListing.City.LocationID", searchLocation.LocationID))
            .List<DateBlock>();
```

Giving me the error of:

```
could not resolve property: HaveListing.City.LocationID of: Dm.Mvc.Data.UserObjects.DateBlock_US
```

I can't, for the life of me, see where the differences could lie. Can anyone see something jumping out at them? Or, is there any way to get underlying HQL from a Criteria (or similar) so that I might compare them?

In case it's any help, my weird-o mapping is as follows:

```
public class Map<T> : NotNullableClassMap<T> where T : DateBlock
    {
        public void BaseMap()
        {
            Id(b => b.m_BlockCode).Column("BlockCode").GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
            Map(b => b.StartDate);
            Map(b => b.EndDate);
            Map(b => b.BlockType);

        }
    }

public class DateBlock_US : DateBlock {
    public class DateBlock_US_Map : Map<DateBlock_US>
    {
        public DateBlock_US_Map()
        {
            base.BaseMap();
            References<HaveListing_US>(b => b.HaveListing).Column("HaveListing_US_id");
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said, it works fine in every way except this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that a solution is to add a CreateAlias, like so:

```
dbSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(DateBlock_US))
        .CreateAlias("HaveListing","h")
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("h.City.LocationID", searchLocation.LocationID))
        .List<DateBlock>();
```

However, I'd be very grateful if anyone could shed any light on *why* it is necessary.